# iOS - Popover with scrollview content size is bigger than the popover size in iPhone

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller, popover

I'm new to iOS development so it may be a simple problem that i can not see, the thing is I have a scrollview inside of a popover and I can't find the way to make it look right.

The problem is highly probably related to the fact that I am trying to use a not full screen popover in iPhone. In this particular case it could be resolved changing that, but I would like to know how to do it, if possible.

Also it's only scrollable sideways and i want it to be only scrollable in the vertical axis. (I didn't look into this yet, so it may be really simple and is not important)

Here is an image of the problem:

[Image of how the view doesnt fit in the pop over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JepqU.jpg)

There is text to the left of the popover and to the right the image continues

Here is my code

```
@objc func foo(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popup")

    popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width * 0.75, height: view.bounds.height * 0.75)

    let pVC = popupVC.popoverPresentationController
    pVC?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    pVC?.delegate = self
    pVC?.sourceView = sender.view!
    pVC?.sourceRect = sender.view!.bounds

    let popView = popupVC.view!

    let nosotrosFoto = UIImageView()
    nosotrosFoto.image = UIImage(named: "foto.png")
    nosotrosFoto.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    nosotrosFoto.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let nosotrosTexto = UILabel()
    nosotrosTexto.text = sobreNosotrosString
    nosotrosTexto.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nosotrosTexto.numberOfLines = 0

    let nosotrosContent = UIView()
    nosotrosContent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nosotrosContent.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
    nosotrosContent.addSubview(nosotrosTexto)
    nosotrosContent.addSubview(nosotrosFoto)

    nosotrosFoto.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosContent.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosFoto.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosContent.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosFoto.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosContent.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    nosotrosTexto.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosFoto.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosTexto.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosFoto.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosTexto.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosFoto.rightAnchor).isActive = true

    let nosotrosScroll = UIScrollView(frame: popView.bounds)
    nosotrosScroll.contentSize =  popupVC.preferredContentSize
    nosotrosScroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nosotrosScroll.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    nosotrosScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    nosotrosScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    nosotrosScroll.addSubview(nosotrosContent)

    popView.addSubview(nosotrosScroll)

    nosotrosScroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosScroll.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popView.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosScroll.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popView.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    nosotrosScroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    self.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you miss some constraints for

1- between the nosotrosContent & scrollView

```
nosotrosContent.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosScroll.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
nosotrosContent.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosScroll.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
nosotrosContent.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosScroll.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
nosotrosContent.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosScroll.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
nosotrosContent.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: popView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

2- height of the photo , say it 100

```
nosotrosFoto.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
```

3- bottom constraint between nosotrosTexto & nosotrosContent

```
nosotrosTexto.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nosotrosTexto.bottomAnchor , constant: -20 ).isActive = true
```